# PHP , Laravel- Structure the code for the following data

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

I have two tables

`questions` with columns `id(PK)`, `name`.

and

`answers` with `columns` `id(PK)`,`question_id(FK)`,`answer_!`,`answer_2`,`answer_3`,`answer_4`,

The data i am getting is that each question have its multiple answers.

[image: Request Values]

What is the best way to insert it into `DB` via Laravel.

I have tried but didn't got success.

Comment: Any code block please?

Comment: @HilmiErdemKEREN Bad code block mate... I am writing and removing code. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example: *Please note that non of the code blocks are actually tested.*

Database structure:

**Questions**: id, name (A question has many answers)

**Answers**:   id, question_id, name (An answer belongs to a question)

I have wrote 2 model files and a Http Controller file:

**Question Model:**

```
<?php
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Question Extends Model
{
    // Relation
    public function answers()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Answer::class);
    }
}
```

**Answer Model:**

```
<?php
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Answer Extends Model
{
    // Relation
    public function question()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Question::class);
    }
}
```

If you want to save all questions at once, a **controller** like that (with `try-catch`es and `transaction`s etc.) should help:

**Controller For the Orginal Request**

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Question;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class QuestionsController Extends Controller
{
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $questions = $request->input("question");
        $answers = $request->input("answer");
        foreach($questions as $qKey => $qName) {
            $question = Question::create(["name" => $qName]);

            if(array_key_exists($qKey, $answers) && is_array($answers[$qKey]))
            {
                foreach($answers[$qKey] as $aKey => $aName) {
                    if(! is_null($aName)) {
                        $question->answers()->create(["name" => $aName]);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

*For people who can change the request parameters, a better way of doing that is:*

Change the **request** if you can as follows:

```
{
    "questions": [
        {
            "name": "What ever",
            "answers": [
                {"name": "answer 1 of this question"},
                {"name": "answer 2 of this question"}
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "What ever 2",
            "answers": [
                {"name": "answer 1 of this question"},
                {"name": "answer 2 of this question"}
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

That will help you a lot to parse them later.

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Question;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class AlternateQuestionsController Extends Controller
{
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        foreach($request->input("questions", []) as $questionPayload) {
            $question = Question::create(["name" => $questionPayload["name"]);

            foreach($questionPayload["answers"] as $answerPayload) {
                if(is_array($answerPayload)) {
                    $question->answers()->create(["name" => $answerPayload["name"]])
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Mate the request cannot be change, Its the need.

Comment: Is there anyway to alter your `foreach()` ?

Comment: Sure there is. I will add it too.

Comment: Check the answer again please.

Answer (score 1):

You should learn about Laravel relationships:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships

In your case that would be one-to-many relationship (one question - multiple answers).

Comment: How ? How can i use relationships ?

Comment: You need to read first about the eloquent. I am not getting your way. You need to save question and then answers one by one by using their Model class.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest a way It may help you. You can make an intermediate table that keeps relations between **question** and **answer** model.

**question_answer:**

```
| answer_id | question_id |
| --------- | ----------- |
|    1      |      2      |
```

And retrieve the answers of the question like this:

```
Question::find($questionId)->answer()->get();
or
Question::find($questionId)->answer;
```

In your **question** model add this method:

```
public function answer()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Answer','question_answer','answer_id ','question_id ');
    }
```

if you take a look at this page you will understand more

https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many